# Django in shared hosting/cpanel .htaccess: Invalid command error

Tags: django, passenger, cpanel, wsgi, django-wsgi

hey guys i have the issue with my django app so what should i do?i have shared hosting account on which i am trying to upload my django app,
this is the code of .htaccess file

> DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
>
> PassengerAppRoot "/home/dasawork/store"
>
> PassengerBaseURI "/test"
>
> PassengerPython "/home/dasawork/virtualenv/store/3.5/bin/python3.5"
>
> DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

it worked at night first when i set up my python app in cpanel and then in the morning it wasn't working and giving the error "/home/dasawork/public_html/test/.htaccess: Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration". my hosting providers changed my root dir name! like when it worked it was "'/newhome/dasawork/...." but on the morning it was changed to "/home/dasawork/..." so can this cause the problem ?
please help

Comment: The core error `Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled ...` is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031785/invalid-command-passengerapproot-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-no but as you've said you're on some sort of shared hosting, I'm not sure what kind of access you'd have to resolve the error by reinstalling modules. Shouldn't `PassengerBaseURI "/test"` be on a new line?