# Passenger Resolve Symlinks In Document Root Is Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, server

When I run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I get the following error

> Invalid command 'PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>   sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/46031785/4758119

Comment: similar https://serverfault.com/a/895705